# Displaying images in php using a table

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am using this code but it is giving me errors. How do I display the images in a table using php?

```
echo “<td>”.<img src=\”=View.php?image_id=$row[’Id’]>”.”</td>”;
```

I am getting a syntax error, how can I fix this?

Thank You

Comment: Your quotes are the wrong type (curly)

Comment: Curly quotes; beautiful yet *deadly*. Don't edit/create code with a Word processor (or copy from certain Web sites). Use a real, honest to goodness IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong double quotes, wrong single quotes and you are missing to escape one double quote and missing also a double quote in concatenation, so change to

```
echo "<td>"."<img src=\"=View.php?image_id=$row['Id']>\""."</td>";
```

Comment: Thanks, however I am still receiving this error when I change the code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery_test\listImages.php on line 45 –  user3430970 Mar 18 at 21:21